# Data transfer insert into by chunk of 10,000 rows each time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert, data-transfer

I get a 6M rows table need to sent to another server each day.
it seems never finish when i do testing by:

```
insert into serverA.dbName.dbo.table1
select * from serverB.dbName.dbo.table1
```

is there such thing like "do 10000 rows each time"

something like

```
insert into serverA.dbName.dbo.table1
select * from serverB.dbName.dbo.table1
**by numOfRowEachTime=10000**
```

Otherwise i will write a loop.

Comment: I'd write a cursor. Or do it [programmatically](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6/).

Comment: It's a bad idea to use cursor 90% of the times.

Comment: If your SQL Server licensing allows you to setup Integration Service, you could use it. The destinations can be simply configured with chunks.

Comment: The best way to copy over 6M rows daily is to use BulkCopy using either DTS or write a small app that uses SQLBulkCopy with the batch size of 100,000 for optimal performance. In your case its a long running process as SQL server logs each insert operation. hence logging 6M inserts would take considerable amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

6 million rows in a single transaction is a pretty sizable chunk to begin with, and DML statements across linked servers aren't great either. But two methods to consider (that have worked for me) are:

1. If there is an easy way to copy them in order (such as an ID field) then you can:

   - Keep track of the last ID sent in a new table on ServerB
   - Write a proc on ServerB that does a loop similar to the following:

     ```sql
     DECLARE @StartingID INT = 1,
             @EndingID INT,
             @DataToTransport NVARCHAR(MAX);

     SELECT @StartingID = StartingID FROM dbo.ProcessStatus;

     WHILE (1 = 1)
     BEGIN
        ;WITH cte AS
        (
           SELECT TOP (10000) t1.ID,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.ID ASC) AS [RowNum]
           FROM   dbo.Table1 t1
           WHERE t1.ID >= @StartingID
        )
        SELECT TOP (1) @EndingID = cte.[ID] FROM cte
        ORDER BY cte.[RowNum] DESC;

        IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BEGIN
           UPDATE dbo.ProcessStatus SET StartingID = 1;
           BREAK; -- reset to start at the beginning and exit
        END;

        SET @DataToTransport = (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), (
            SELECT t1.* FROM dbo.Table1 t1
            WHERE t1.ID BETWEEN @StartingID AND @EndingID
            FOR XML RAW));

        EXEC [ServerA].[dbName].[dbo].Table1_ImportFromServerB @DataToTransport;

        UPDATE dbo.ProcessStatus SET StartingID = @StartingID;

        SET @StartingID = (@EndingID + 1);
     END;
     ```
   - Write a proc on ServerA -- [dbName].[dbo].Table1_ImportFromServerB -- that accepts the NVARCHAR(MAX) input param, converts it to XML, and does an `INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT ... FROM (either @XMLvariable.Nodes or OPENXML)`
   - Sending over a batch wrapped up as XML to a stored proc over a Linked Server is *much* faster than doing a straight INSERT over a Linked Server
   - You have to send the XML as NVARCHAR(MAX) as XML is not allowed for sending over a Linked Server
   - The `[ProcessStatus]` table is just to keep track of the current position in case the process fails and hence it can start where it left off, or you can even set a time limit or counter of X iterations and schedule to run from a SQL Agent job every N minutes or so (which is how I have always done it).
2. Use SQLCLR to make use of the `SqlBulkCopy` class that is designed for this type of task. It is essentially the same API that is used by BCP, OPENROWSET(BULK...), and BULK INSERT. You can write your own CLR-based stored procedure, or there is one already done and available for free in the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library (which I am the author of, but again, it is free). The stored procedure is called `DB_BulkCopy` and allows for setting a batch size.